# Produce a simple Video - uncompressed, frame by frame

Tags: java, algorithm, video

I need to an algorithm, to write frames (Pictures) into a file, which can be read by some Video-Cutting/Producing-Software to work with.

So I got frames, and I want to give them a input into a function/Method.
Let's do i in Java.

How can I do this?
Is there a simple way, I can write videofiles without using any systemcodecs?

I just need a uncompressed video with a constant Framerate (25 fps or 50 fps)
that will take my true-Color pictures (2D-arrays of Colors), so that I can use that video in my Videoprogramm to work with.

I never found any fileformat that fits to that.

Can You help me?

Greetings from Austria, and thanks. Flo.

Comment: The answer strongly depends on what the video program accepts as input, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the program you want to use to further process your movie you can also simply create PNGs (or TGAs or BMPs) for the single frames. VirtualDub e.g. can use images as frames for a movie.

Answer (score 1):

The AVI container format can contain streams of uncompressed video, of which there are many types to choose from. Have a look here http://fourcc.org/ at the RGB and YUV formats, and here http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf for details on the AVI file format.